# Pyspark - convert a dataframe column with month number to another dataframe column having month name

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I am trying to convert a dataframe month number column to the corresponding month name column. I tried the following approach -

```
df_month_name = df.withColumn('month_name',calendar.month_abbr['MONTH_NUMBER'])
```

I got the error:

```
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'month_abbr'
```

Please let me know if there is any other better way. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `to_date` to convert the months to date then use `date_format` to get month names :

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = spark.createDataFrame([("1",), ("2",), ("3",), ("4",), ("5",)], ["month_number"])

df1 = df.withColumn("month_name", F.date_format(F.to_date("month_number", "MM"), "MMMM")) \
    .withColumn("month_abbr", F.date_format(F.to_date("month_number", "MM"), "MMM"))

df1.show()

#+------------+----------+----------+
#|month_number|month_name|month_abbr|
#+------------+----------+----------+
#|           1|   January|       Jan|
#|           2|  February|       Feb|
#|           3|     March|       Mar|
#|           4|     April|       Apr|
#|           5|       May|       May|
#+------------+----------+----------+
```

Note that for Spark 3, you need to set `spark.conf.set("spark.sql.legacy.timeParserPolicy", "LEGACY")` to convert month number to date.

---

You can also use map column that holds a mapping `month_number -> month_abbr`:

```
import calendar
import itertools
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

months = F.create_map(*[
    F.lit(m) for m in itertools.chain(*[(x, calendar.month_abbr[x]) for x in range(1, 12, 1)])
])

df1 = df.withColumn("month_abbr", months[F.col("month_number")])
```

---

Another way using UDF:

```
import calendar
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

month_name = F.udf(lambda x: calendar.month_name[int(x)])
month_abbr = F.udf(lambda x: calendar.month_abbr[int(x)])

df1 = df.withColumn("month_name", month_name(F.col("month_number"))) \
    .withColumn("month_abbr", month_abbr(F.col("month_number")))
```

Answer (score 1):

If someone wants to do this in scala, you can do it as below :

```
//Sample Data
val df = Seq(("1"),("2"),("3"),("4"),("5"),("6"),("7"),("8"),("9"),("10"),("11"),("12")).toDF("month_number")

import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val df1 = df.withColumn("Month_Abbr",date_format(to_date($"month_number","MM"),"MMM"))
display(df1)
```

You can see the output as below :

[image]